# How to show or hide cursor on WinForms MS chart, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, microsoft-chart-controls

I have to use System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart in my project

I created hair cross pair of System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Cursor() on a chart;
I would like to show or hide these CursorX, CursorY on chart if needed.
The idea is to toggle cursor on chart by DoubleClick event.
I cannot find any property (i.e. CursorX.Visible) or method (i.e. CursorX.hide()) to do it.

To hide, I tried to copy cursor object to global private cursor object and dispose cursor object from chart.ChartArea; to show - [re]create cursor object again from global object.
But it caused more troubles because now I need to check everywhere if cursor object exists

Anybody knows a better way of hiding cursor?

P.S. I also used before National Instruments Measurements Studio chart - that is designed mach better, everything is thought out and much easier...

Comment: Why cant you Cursor.hide() on mousehover? The idea is you want the cursor gone when it goes over your chart?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Chart.ChartAreas[0].Cursor; only  Chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX and Chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorY. Both do not have method Hide(). 

Why to hide - in one situation I want to have only vert cursor line so when I drag it somewhere on a form I would show Y values from multiple traces (Series) at this X, in another situation show only horizontal line which sticks to max or min of trace. Or it can be too crowded so I want to hide cursor to de-clatter a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way:
To make cursor "disappear", set ChartArea[0].CursorX.LineDashStyle to "NotSet"

To [re]appear, set this property to anything else from the choices: "Solid, Dot, Dash, etc."

Example:
chartArea2.CursorX.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Solid;

Comment: I had the same problem, so thank you for answering your own question.